# How to get more info about socket file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, socket

For a socket file likes this:

```
# ls -alti socket
14112 srw------- 1 root root 0 Nov 15 20:03 socket
# cat socket
cat: socket: No such device or address
```

Since `cat` command is useless here, is there any method to get more info about the socket file? Such as which port it is listening on? etc.

Comment: Only TCP and UDP sockets have the concept of port, or to be more precise, unix socket domains do not have associated ports.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A socket is a file for processes to exchange data. You can see more data about it using the `netstat`, `lsof`, and `fuser` commands.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket):

> A Unix domain socket or IPC socket (inter-process communication socket) is a data communications endpoint for exchanging data between processes executing on the same host operating system. Like named pipes, Unix domain sockets support transmission of a reliable stream of bytes (SOCK_STREAM, compare to TCP).

Comment: So socket file is just a UNIX domain socket?

Comment: Exactly, it was what I tried to convey.